# YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds displays blank page in all the browsers

Tags: iframe, youtube

I have been referring to  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference and I have created one test.html with the code under 'Getting started" section. The html page appears blank in all the browsers. Could anyone please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Appreciate your help.